# Copying string in reverse order using push and pop in Assembly,can't see output by calling writeString

Tags: assembly, stack, masm, irvine32

Only Problem is that i can't see output by calling writeString to make sure that string is successfully copied into destination or not

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
string BYTE "kashif",0
dest  BYTE 0
.code
main PROC

mov ecx,lengthof string
mov esi,offset string

k:
mov al,[esi]
push ax
inc esi
loop k

mov ecx,lengthof string
mov edi,offset dest

a:
pop ax
mov [edi],al
call writeChar
inc edi
loop a
```

by calling writeChar i can see output in reverse order i.e fihsak it means that push,pop is working fine

```
mov edx,offset dest
call writeString
```

but here i can't see any output by calling writeString

```
exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: `writeString` probably expects one byte per character. When you place the string on the stack you're pushing a _word_ per character. Another issue is that you only reserve a single byte of space at `dest`.

Comment: Looks like you're copying the terminating zero to the beginning of `dest`. Loop one less. ("count" starts with 1, "index" starts with 0)

Comment: Oh, and `dest` is only a byte. Not enough for your reversed string!

Comment: @Michael but how can I push byte register? It is not allowed to push 8 bit register.

Comment: @FrankKotler i changed dest to WORD and started edi from 0 but even though problem is there.And i can't be able to inc ecx, it gives runtime error

Comment: `WORD` still isn't enough to fit your reversed string in `dest`. What I had in mind was `dec ecx` - before both loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reversing a string does not make it any longer or shorter. You need to initialize the destination the same way you setup the source.

```
string BYTE "kashif",0
dest   BYTE "xxxxxx",0
```

Here the **lengthof** operator returns 7 because it will include the terminating zero. That terminating zero is not a byte you want to include in the reversing operation and so you must decrement the count.

```
mov ecx,lengthof string
dec ecx
```

Comment: Is there any wany to push/pop byte register instead of word or dword ?

Comment: The CPU does not allow to push/pop a byte register. If you need to store a series of byte values on the stack you could partially unroll the loop involved to get 2 succesive values into a word register and then push the word.